# How to remove relation from django model with ManyToMany field?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, relational-database, django-orm

How to remove relation from model with ManyToMany field?

I've got a model with ManyToManyField relation. I need to remove relation but not data from the following model:

```
class TxHomes(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    home_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    geo_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    payload = models.JSONField()
```

Django ORM got tables generated:

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table main_txhomes
(
    home_id  integer unsigned not null primary key,
    name     varchar(255),
    geo_name varchar(255),
    ...
);
create table main_txhomes_user
(
    id           primary key autoincrement,
    txhomes_id ...,
    user_id ...
);
```

When I apply to do that with a following code

```
TxHomes.objects.filter(
    home_id__in=TxHomes.objects.filter(user=USER_ID).values('home_id')
    ,user=USER_ID).delete()
```

i got entire data deleted from main_txhomes

I want to keep data in main_txhomes table, what i need is to **delete relations from main_txhomes_user** table. How to do that?

Comment: You want to remove all relationships for a given User?

Comment: Yes. Need to remove all relations for the user.

Comment: Does something like `User.objects.get(id=USER_ID).txhomes_set.clear()` work?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is found:

```
User.objects.get(id=USER_ID).txhomes_set.clear()
```

This is how we remove all relation to txhomes table for the user